# Avatar image between two divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i'm just wondering if there is a more elegant solution to achieve the following

I'm trying to put an avatar image in the vertical middle of two divs like here:
http://notch.tumblr.com/
is there a bootstrap css class to achieve that so that i dont have to add these by myself?

Comment: show your code! I don't want to hunt for it!

Comment: Nothign hard. it's an absolute element at 50% left and half-minus margin-left. Do it by your self.

Comment: Did you inspect the element to see what styles are applied to it?

Comment: i've already accomplished it, i was just wondering if there's a bootstrap-only way ;)

Comment: nice to see my question being downvoted for no reason :)

Answer (score 0):

All it takes:

```
<div class="roundedCenter">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.roundedCenter > div{
  /*Change or remove and set as a separate class:  */
  width:160px; height:160px;

  /*Don't change:  */
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  left:50%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```css
.row{height:150px;}


.roundedCenter > div{
  /*Change:  */
  width:160px; height:160px;
  
  /*Don't change:  */
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  left:50%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="background:#f8a;"></div>
<div class="roundedCenter">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="background:#8af;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, that was my way-to-go :) seems like there is no bootstrap-way for that